# Execute batch script once a day only

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am new at working with the batch scripts and I have got a scenario which i have to take care very soon. I have a batch script that is responsible to send sms to the users. I want this batch script to run once a day only no matter how many times I try to execute it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am curious. Why would you ask users to run the batch file?
You should look at scheduling commands using `SCHTASKS`, the Task Scheduler on Windows 10.

See: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-task-using-task-scheduler-command-prompt

If you insist on user run batch file, you have to use some kind of persistent run-once flag. You could implement something using the following logic:

1. Check for existence of a file named .runonce-yyyymmdd in a specific directory
2. If the file doesnt exist, create it. Contents doesnt matter. A zero byte file is fine.
   a. Delete the previous day's .runonce-yyyymmdd file if it exists.
   b. Proceed with execution of the rest of the batch file.
3. If the file exists, stop (because the batch file has already run for the day).

Answer (score 0):

I belive it's date time format independent:

```
:: Run once a day
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ("%date%") DO SET today=%%a%%b%%c
IF EXIST %today%.day (
    @echo Already ran!
    timeout /T 5
) ELSE (
    del *.day 
    @echo today=%today% > %today%.day
    
    the_command_that_will_run_once_a_day.exe

)
```

I use this snippet in a batch file which runs on every hour using task scheduler.